# Does mongoose support a declarative way to do sanitization (like lowercasing) when doing sets/finds?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sanitization

Consider a field `email` which I'd like to set and query (`findOne`) over. I've created an unique index. Moreover, I'd like to enforce all email-addresses are lowercase according to best practice.

Of course I can make sure all my controllers that set and/or query by `email` will property lowercase first, but this is error-prone. Is there a way to offload this declaratively to mongoose/mongo instead? I.e.: passing `Some@Example.com` to Mongoose will properly by sanitized to `some@example.com` before setting the value or querying the collection.

Answer (score 2):

You could use pre save middleware. This is coding but it would ensure that any call to save your document would lower case the email, no matter where it was saved from

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    user.email = user.email.toLowerCase();
    next();
});
```

Comment: Yeah. Just found being able to do `lowercase: true` and `trim: true` right in the schema, which is more akin to what I want. However, both your suggestion as well as mine don't address the query part.